# CSS - Nested table border showing. How do I stop this?

Tags: css

I am using ie 8.
I have the following CSS where I want to show the border for the outer table, but not the table nested inside one of the cells;

```
table#ScheduledLeaveCalendar
{
table-layout:fixed;
}

/* Calendar that shows annual leave */
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar td, #ScheduledLeaveCalendar th 
{
    font-size:0.8em;
    border:1px solid #2906A6;   /* dark blue */

}
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar th 
{
    width:30px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 3px 4px 3px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#6640EE;   /* blue */
    color:#ffffff;
}
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar td
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#ScheduledLeaveCalendar table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This CSS gives me
[image: When splitting the cell in 2, the border becomes thicker]

The Markup is;

```
<table id="ScheduledLeaveCalendar">

    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="6">Oct 2011</th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <th>F</th><th></th><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>T</th><th>F</th><th></th><th>M</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>14</th><th></th><th>17</th><th>18</th><th>19</th><th>20</th><th>21</th><th></th><th>24</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%"><tr><td />
<td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;AnnualLeaveColour" />
</tr></table></td>
    <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%"><tr><td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;AnnualLeaveColour" />
<td />
</tr></table></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>
    <td class="StandardCellHeight&#32;DefaultColour"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Dqm68/1/

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle demo that looks like your screenshot? I tried, but it's not quite right: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Dqm68/

Comment: I have just done that. I am new to jsFiddle and I should start using it. http://jsfiddle.net/Dqm68/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add another line to remove the border from the nested table td.

```
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar table td {border:none}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Dqm68/3/

Comment: A lot of the problem was that the cache got in the way of showing a solution that worked. This one did and I am sure the other did as well!

Comment: use ctrl+f5 or this neat firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-reloader/ :D

Comment: I was using ctrl+F5, but I did not know about the FF reloader. Thank you for that.

Comment: its worth noting that css reloader only reloads the referenced css and not inline css

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
#ScheduledLeaveCalendar td td {
    border: 0;
}
```

which means the `td` elements that are nested in other `td` elements should have no border..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Dqm68/5/